# webkit - center link text

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am trying to center the text of an href element, on webkit browsers (chrome/safari).

This is the html:

```
<div>
        <a onclick="check(1);" id="check1" class="linkText">center please</a>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
.linkText, .linkText:hover
 {
margin: 0 auto;
background-image:url(/images/q.png);
width:280px;
height:57px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:Transparent;
border:none;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:normal !important;
color:Black !important;
text-shadow: none !important;
display: -webkit-box;
text-align:center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
box-align: center;
    }
```

The result I get is shown in the image attaced:
[image]

Any ideas?
10X!

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? To show what you've got so far, and what we're working with.

Comment: Also, would you want people with other browsers to be able to see it too?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have never used JS Fiddle demo, I will try to post there.

Comment: @MrLister - this will eventually be used only on iPhone browsers.

Comment: By removing display: -webit-box , the text moves to center (horizontally). Then you would need to figure something for vertical alignmnet

Comment: @UdiI See my latest answer. It will solve your problem. Have attached demo too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your css!

```
-webkit-box-pack:center;
```

It will solve the issue.

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/yscPm/

Answer (score 0):

tag "a" is inline and inline tag has not width.  set display as block

```
<div>
    <a onclick="check(1);" id="check1" class="linkText">center please</a>
    <style>
        .linkText, .linkText:hover {
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: url(/images/q.png);
            width: 280px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: Transparent;
            border: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: normal !important;
            color: Black !important;
            text-shadow: none !important;
            display: -webkit-box;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            box-align: center;
            display: table-cell; 
                    vertical-align: middle; 
                    background-color: #ccc; 
                    height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it centers the text horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: for vertical alignment insert link in item with table-cell display. then set vertical align to middle

Comment: 10X, but the text is still vertically not centered.

Comment: set height for div. i Check it code work on firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block or block for link css. As  is not a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add text-align to the div?

Else use this

```
<div><center>
    <a onclick="check(1);" id="check1" class="linkText">center please</a></center>
```

Comment: Re your "else": since `<center>` is a block just like `<div>`, you can replace the `div` with a `center` instead of introducing a new `center` into the DOM tree. However, applying `text-align:center` is better in many ways.

Comment: Why would you recommend the use of a [deprecated tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/center)?

Comment: Kind of inexperienced. Don't know much about the specs. Will keep in mind, thanks!